# Will I get all subgroups of order p?

Tags: group-theory

Lets say I have a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of order p.

Then I look at the family: $\{gHg^{-1}: g \in G\}$. Then since conjugation leads to an isomorphism I get that every group in the collection is a subgroup of order p(and hence every non-trivial element has order p). But do I get all subgrops of order p doing this, or can some be missed?

And does it help if I assume H is normal?

Comment: If $H$ is normal, then $g^{-1}Hg=H.$ Therefore any abelian group $G?$

Answer (score 1):

Conjugation is trivial in abelian groups, and if the group $\;G\;$ is **not** a cyclic group, it will have for some prime $\;p\;$ two different subgroups of order $\;p\;$ , which can't then be conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

in case $G$ is non-abelian note that if  $p | ord(G)$ but $p^2$ does not, then you may apply Sylow's theorem to conclude that all subgroups of order $p$ are conjugates

Answer (score 0):

Take any abelian group $G$. Then the conjugates will always be just $H$ again, so obviously you will not get all the subgroups of order $p$ as there is no reason for there to be only one subgroup of order $p$.

In any group $G$, if $H$ is normal then it each conjugate of $H$ is again $H$ (the previous case is a special case of this one), so again it won't necessarily give all subgroups of order $p$.

Even if $H$ is not normal, there is no reason in the world that its conjugates will give all subgroups of order $p$, as plenty of examples will show.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume $H$ to be normal your familiy just contain $H$.

Actually this is a good question and the following example will go further than your question :

$$G:=\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{4\mathbb{Z}}\times\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}} $$

then you get $2$ subgroups of order $2$ given $H_1$ generated by $(2,0)$ and $H_2$ generated by $(0,1)$.

You can show that there can't be a group automorphism $\Psi$ of $G$ such that $\Psi(2,0)=(0,1)$. the reason is that $(2,0)=(1,0).(1.0)$ (it is a square in the group $G$) and $(0,1)$ cannot be put with this form.

In particular you cannot have that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conjugate to each other.